# Using DataGrid ItemDataBound Event to Check Value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've got a DataGrid where the datasource is bound with a SqlDataReader object:

```
  SqlDataReader areader = runner.Reader;
  dgSearchResults.DataSource = areader;
  dgSearchResults.DataBind();
```

I've created an ItemDataBound event for my grid and I want to check the Value of a specific Column/Cell that while each item is bound so I can enable/disable some flags.

How can I get the value of a specific cell "SvcID" on the ItemDataBound?

Here is my code:

```
 public void dgSearchResults_ItemDataBound(object sender,  DataGridItemEventArgs e)
    {

        if (ViewState["SvcIDs"] != null)
        {
            if (e.Item != null)
            {
                var svcIds = (List<int>) ViewState["SvcIDs"];

                if (svcIds.Contains(Convert.ToInt32(**DataGrid SvcID Goes Here**))
                {
                    //TODO: enable/disable some icons
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've used RowDataBound events before but not for a DataGrid control, and the required steps are a bit different it seems.

What is the code to check the value of Column "SvcID" in my DataGrid against my SvcIds (using an Index) List?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following to access the cells:

```
e.Item.Cells[index].Text;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagriditemeventargs.item.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I was actually expecting the .Text property to have a Column name but it does in fact have a column value whenever e.Item.ItemIndex >= 0 !

Answer (score 1):

if your text is in second cell.

ex 
e.Item.Cells[2].Text

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cant index the Cell collection using a column name or the databound field name.

To do that you need to know the index of the datafield (e.g. `SvcID` in your case) and index the `Row` object. If you are using `AutogenerateColumns` then the index would be based on the order of columns you are querying from the database.

Then you can handle the `RowDataBound` event, which has an event argument of type `GridViewRowEventArgs` that gives u access to the DataGridView row instance. then you can do something like this:

```
string val= e.Row.Cells(index).Text;
```

Comment: Getting the index of the datafield isn't an issue. However, I dont have access to e.Row.Cells?

Comment: **e** is ur event arguments. Its a parameter to ur procedure. So what do you mean by 'u dont have access to it?'

Comment: ohh my bad .. you can use `RowDataBound` event instead